# How do I unit test HTTP Digest Authentication in Flask?

Tags: python, flask, python-unittest, digest-authentication, flask-httpauth

I've got a flask app that implements a REST api. For reasons, I'm using HTTP Digest Authentication. I've used the Flask-HTTPAuth library to implement the digest authentication and it works; however, I am unable to authenticate in the unit tests.

For the unit tests, prior to setting up the authentication, I'm doing something like this:

```
class FooTestCase(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.app = foo.app.test_client()

    def test_root(self):
        response = self.app.get('/')
        # self.assert.... blah blah blah
```

Prior to implementing the authentication, this was fine. Now I get a 401, which is expected as the initial response for a digest auth request. I've searched and searched and followed a few suggestions related to http basic auth (using parameters data = { #various stuff} and follow_redirects=True) but I've had no success.

Does anyone have a clue how to implement unittests in this case?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unfortunately digest authentication is harder to test or bypass in Flask-HTTPAuth.

One option is to actually calculate the correct hashes and perform the full authentication during tests. You can see a few examples of this in the [Flask-HTTPAuth unit tests](https://github.com/miguelgrinberg/Flask-HTTPAuth/tree/master/tests). Here is one:

```
def test_digest_auth_login_valid(self):
    response = self.client.get('/digest')
    self.assertTrue(response.status_code == 401)
    header = response.headers.get('WWW-Authenticate')
    auth_type, auth_info = header.split(None, 1)
    d = parse_dict_header(auth_info)

    a1 = 'john:' + d['realm'] + ':bye'
    ha1 = md5(a1).hexdigest()
    a2 = 'GET:/digest'
    ha2 = md5(a2).hexdigest()
    a3 = ha1 + ':' + d['nonce'] + ':' + ha2
    auth_response = md5(a3).hexdigest()

    response = self.client.get(
        '/digest', headers={
            'Authorization': 'Digest username="john",realm="{0}",'
                             'nonce="{1}",uri="/digest",response="{2}",'
                             'opaque="{3}"'.format(d['realm'],
                                                   d['nonce'],
                                                   auth_response,
                                                   d['opaque'])})
    self.assertEqual(response.data, b'digest_auth:john')
```

In this example, the username is `john` and the password is `bye`. Presumably you have some predetermined credentials for a user that can be used in unit tests, so you would plug those in the `a1` variable above. This authentication dance can be included in an auxiliary function that wraps the sending of a request during tests, that way you don't have to repeat this in every test.

Comment: Yup. I need to make the request, get the 401, construct the auth digest headers based on the return (which I can find in the response object in pycharm). Just like the code you copied and pasted is doing... 

On the money, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It's not neccessary to use real-world authentication in tests. Either disable authentication when running tests or create test user and use this test user in tests.

For example:

```
    @digest_auth.get_password
    def get_pw(username):
        if running_from_tests():
            if username == 'test':
                return 'testpw'
            else:
                return None
        else:
            # ... normal auth that you have
```

Of couse this test user must never be active in production :) For implementation of `running_from_tests()` see [Test if code is executed from within a py.test session](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25188119/test-if-code-is-executed-from-within-a-py-test-session) (if you are using py.test).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'm all set with setting up a test user and getting the password. I can do that right from the DB. My issue is with the test_client().get() function.

If I were to run the flask server, and then from a different python function if I were to use the requests library, I can do something like this:

    from requests.auth import HTTPDigestAuth

    result = requests.get('http://127.0.0.1:5000/', auth=HTTPDigestAuth('test', 'mytestpw'))

That'll utilize the digest auth set up on the server to log in just fine. But how do I do that process in test_client().get()?

Comment: Sorry, just looked up formatting in comments. The code from above if not clear:

`from requests.auth import HTTPDigestAuth 

result = requests.get('127.0.0.1:5000/', auth=HTTPDigestAuth('test', 'mytestpw'))`

Comment: thanks for taking the time to search. I have run across that a few times during my search but I'm unclear how to make this work for digest auth. With [basic auth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication), a handshake is not required and simply sending the authenticate in the header as that code is doing works fine. With [digest auth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digest_access_authentication#Example_with_explanation), a handshake is required. ....

Oh... For Pete's sake. Of course. I'll get the response with all the info I need to do the calculations myself. derp.