# Running all pytest tests inside a 3rd party application's custom interpreter

Tags: python, pytest

*TL;DR:* How do I get a pytest plugin to redirect the running tests to a spawned process (inside a different environment/python interpreter)?

---

I'm developing a python script that is run by a python interpreter embedded inside a third party application (Namely, [IDA](https://www.hex-rays.com/products/ida/)). I'm now in the process of creating tests for my script using `pytest`, using a `pytest` plugin I wrote for the application. Because the application makes certain modules available only within it's own interpreter any tests must be running in a python interpreter inside the application.

I would like to improve my `pytest` plugin by allowing it to execute the `pytest` session inside the third party application, instead inside a vanilla interpreter.

I know how to cause my tests and `pytest` to run inside the application, which will be something similar to this:

```
subprocess.call("C:\Program Files\IDA\idaq.exe" -S <My script>", shell=True)
```

I'm struggling with where (a `pytest` hook, I assume, but which one?) should I spawn the `pytest` session inside? How can I make sure that test arguments are passed along to the new process?

I assume this is possible as a pytest plugin, because it somewhat resembles the `xdist` plugin.

Comment: Not sure if this helps [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25188119/test-if-code-is-executed-from-within-a-py-test-session)

Comment: Thanks, this might help a bit although I can quite easily find out if my code is running from inside the application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*I will not answer this too in-depth, unless someone comes by and shows interest,  because it'll be kinda long*

I've managed to do this by an approach similar to how pytest-xdist does it's distributed execution, where instead of using [`execnet`](https://pypi.org/project/execnet/) to execute python interpreters remotely, I'm using `subprocess.Popen` to spawn  an instance of the third party application (pointing to a python script for it to execute). I'm using [`multiprocessing.Listener` and `multiprocessing.Client`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#module-multiprocessing.connection) to create a communication channel that can serialize (basic) python objects.

I then, like xdist, created an additional pytest plugin that is being `register`ed by the script the application loads. That pytest plugin registers a handful of hooks using [pytest's available hooking facilities](https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest/blob/master/src/_pytest/hookspec.py) that are then communicated back to the original pytest instance, which will fire them again to simulate them being fired by pytest itself.

For anyone interested in an example which I believe is simpler to understand than pytest-xdist, relevant code can be found on my github [repo](https://github.com/nirizr/pytest-idapro).